# Importing anuglar-material module on single component

Tags: angular

EDIT: Fixed by using @angular/material instead of angular-material. Follow answers below if you are new to angular :)

I'm trying to import "MatToolbarModule" into a single navbar component to use it in navbar.component.html in an angular project but this doesn't seem to be working.
Importing the module in "app.module.ts" and using it in index.html works fine.

Here is my navbar.component.ts :

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {MatToolbarModule} from 'angular-material';

@NgModule({
imports: [MatToolbarModule]
})
//Component decorator and rest of code is untouched
```

In my navbar.component.html:

```
<mat-toolbar>MyTitle</mat-toolbar>
```

Error i get : "If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module."

I'm using angular 5 and latest version of angular-material and its dependecies.
Thank you !

Comment: on the material documentation import looks like this - `import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar`. Or i missing something?

Comment: the package i'm using is angular-material and the same import line is working fine in app.module.ts /w index.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to export everything that you import in the module, its a feature module.

```
// moved this to independent file keeping the app.module cleaner
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatExpansionModule
} from '@angular/material';

const materialModules = [
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatExpansionModule
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    ],
    imports: materialModules,
    exports: materialModules
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Comment: Doing this and importing it to app.module makes it usable in every component in the project ?

Comment: Yes, i am doing same stuff on my project, but u asked for specific case) actually this is how it must be done

Comment: I'm seeing you guys using @angular/material even in the website that's what they are using. I'll try using that package instead and let you know.

Comment: Pretty anfair, but okay. This is the answer for another question) Anyways, if it helped i am glad

Comment: You don't need to place them in the `imports`. Just place them all in the `exports` as a list. You can then remove the `imports` entirely. 
`@NgModule({
  exports: [MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule]`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, answering your question, I recreated your case and all works fine for me.
So I'll provide steps, maybe you missed something.

1. Created Module ;
2. Imported materialModule to it, added to imports;
3. Imported needed component to it, add it do declarations;
4. Imported all module to `app.module` and added to imports after `BrowserAnimationsModule,BrowserModule`.
5. Created  some mat component in my html and all worked for me.

Comment: Well if you are sure that this is the way, thank you for your answer. I'll try to figure out what i'm missing :)